# It is never used else

Tags: grails, if-statement

I am doing some work with Grails and I can't never do the program go through the else part. My code is the following

```
while (pois.hasNext()){
    def poi=pois.next()
    def site = Site.get(poi.site)
    if (!sites.contains(site.id)){
        sites.add([id:site.id.toString(),name:site.name])
    }else{
        println("It has been previously added")
    }
}
```

It should go through as I have checked my DB

Comment: What part of the code is confusing you? Obviously if it never gets to the `else` that means the `if` condition is always true.... so, your `sites` never contains the `site.id` value

Comment: the if condition should never be true. I want to appear just one time each occurence but they are repeated in sites

Comment: I don't know that language/script, but you appear to be adding some kind of object where as you are only checking for a single `id` value/string so I guess that is the issue. (object != string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) :

> Returns true if this collection contains the **specified** element. More formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Your collection contain **pairs** `siteId:siteName`, and you is trying to check that it contains `siteId`.

You should to have one more collection which will contain only `siteId`.

Or, you will change `sites` on `Map` and your code will look like:

```
if (!sites.containsKey(site.id)){
    sites.put(site.id.toString(), site.name)
}else{
    println("It has been previously added")
}
```

Or, you should check all elements from your collection.

```
def isExist = false;
for (def element: sites) {
   if(elemtn.id == site.id) {
       isExist = true;
   }
}

if (!isExist){
    sites.add([id:site.id.toString(),name:site.name])
}else{
    println("It has been previously added")
}
```